# When is the timeout in fsockopen not available?

Tags: php, timeout, environment, fsockopen

I'm making a request from a local webserver (arch linux, php7) to a remote one, which is unavailable because that network is unreachable. Here the timeout appears to be ignored (i.e. `fsockopen` takes about 23 seconds to return instead of the given timeout of 5 seconds).

```php
$timeout = 5;
$start = time();
dbglog($start . ' timeout ' . $timeout); // 1466081215 timeout 5
$socket = fsockopen($server,$port,$errno, $errstr, $timeout);
$end = time();
dbglog($end . ' socket done in ' . ($end-$start) . ' seconds'); // 1466081238 socket done in 23 seconds
```

The [official doku for fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) states the following:

> **Note**:
>
> Depending on the environment, the Unix domain or the optional connect timeout may not be available.

However that's all there is about the environment in which the optional timeout is not available.

Where I can find current documentation for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the socket type. For a local unix socket, timeout does not make so much sense, since everything happens process<-kernel->process. There is no unknown network in-between. So either it fails or it succeeds. But the time it takes depends on the server load.

Comment: Is that the only circumstance? I'm making a request from a local webserver (arch linux, php7) to a remote one which is unavailable because that network is unreachable. Here the timeout appears to be ignored as well.

(maybe I should amend the question with that info)

Comment: And share some code aswell. A minimal working example that contains your problem